# Flume - HDFS Sink batchSize not working

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, flume

I have a Kafka Source, Memory Channel and HDFS Sink composition. What I want to do is to stack 4 messages from the Kafka Source and then put them in HDFS in one single transaction.

```
agent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 4
agent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://127.0.0.1:54310/flume/events/%y-%m-%d/%H%M/%S
agent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
agent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 2
agent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
agent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
```

I don't know why but if I send events every 10 minutes it should be 40 minutes till it registers the data in HDFS but it does after the first event.